iText 8.0.4 upgrade: Getting error while initializing encrypted document
I am in the process of upgrading to iText 8.0.4 from 8.0.1. I have written following unit test.
public class TestEncryption extends TestCase{
public void testGenerateEncryptedPdf() {
    System.out.println("Start test...");
    PdfWriter writer;
    try {
        writer = new PdfWriter(new FileOutputStream("encryptedPdf.pdf"),
                new WriterProperties().setStandardEncryption(
                    "user".getBytes(), 
                    "owner".getBytes(),
                    EncryptionConstants.ALLOW_FILL_IN | EncryptionConstants.ALLOW_SCREENREADERS ,
                    EncryptionConstants.ENCRYPTION_AES_256 | EncryptionConstants.DO_NOT_ENCRYPT_METADATA));
        writer.setCompressionLevel(CompressionConstants.BEST_COMPRESSION);
        writer.setSmartMode(true);
        System.out.println("Initializing encrypted document  ...");
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);
        System.out.println("Done  ...");
        pdfDocument.setTagged();
        Document document = new Document(pdfDocument, new PageSize(PageSize.A4));
        document.setMargins(50, 50, 50, 50);
        document.add(new Paragraph("Sample content."));
        document.close();
        assertNotNull(document);
        System.out.println("End test...");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        fail();
    }
}

}
My pom.xml has the following dependencies:
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>kernel</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>io</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>layout</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>forms</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>bouncy-castle-adapter</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk18on</artifactId>
        <version>1.78</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk18on</artifactId>
        <version>1.78</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

I am getting following error:
com.itextpdf.bouncycastleconnector.BouncyCastleFactoryCreator - Either com.itextpdf:bouncy-castle-adapter or com.itextpdf:bouncy-castle-fips-adapter dependency must be added in order to use BouncyCastleFactoryCreator
Stack trace:
com.itextpdf.kernel.exceptions.PdfException: PdfEncryption exception.
    at com.nasaprs.nspires.pdfAcroformServices.TestEncryption.testGenerateEncryptedPdf(TestEncryption.java:30)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Either com.itextpdf:bouncy-castle-adapter or com.itextpdf:bouncy-castle-fips-adapter dependency must be added in order to use BouncyCastleFactoryCreator
    at com.nasaprs.nspires.pdfAcroformServices.TestEncryption.testGenerateEncryptedPdf(TestEncryption.java:30)

I am not sure why event after adding the dependency, I getting the above error.

This should work just fine. Maybe try to reload pom in your IDE.
Does it work when you run it with "mvn test" on the command line?

@Glenner003 I was running the test on command prompt using "mvn test" command.

Downgrading to iText 8.0.3 everything works fine.

Adding bouncy-castle-fips-adapter dependency resolved this issue.
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>bouncy-castle-fips-adapter</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.4</version>
    </dependency>


That is interesting, adding the bouncy-castle-adapter (as you already had done according to your question) should have sufficed...

@mkl thank you for responding. Actually my unit test worked after adding the bouncy-castle-fips-adapter dependency but I am getting a runtime exception after deploying the code to the server.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.itextpdf.kernel.crypto.securityhandler.StandardHandlerUsingAes256
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bouncycastle.crypto.CryptoServicesRegistrar.isInApprovedOnlyMode()Z [in thread
I am not sure which libraries need to be added. There is definitely some conflict in loading libraries.

The method ryptoServicesRegistrar.isInApprovedOnlyMode is only present in BC-FIPS, not in normal BC. It looks like you're running code that expects BC-FIPS (for example the bouncy-castle-fips-adapter) but have normal BC libraries installed.

There were some bouncy castle libraries on WebLogic's classpath which were conflicting. The issue was resolved by over riding bouncy castle libraries through "pre_classpath" setting.

I have installed nuged  bouncy-castle-fips-adapter dependency and now it works fine!
